# How do i remove this shower valve stem?

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve

How do i remove this shower valve stem? It looks different from others i have seen in DIY videos.

Info:

1. This is a very old house.
2. Shower/Tub is downstairs.
3. Water has been turned off and pressure relieved.

My initial thoughts are:

- Is there a "sheath" on the shower valve - why is it so fat?
- I do not see anything exposed that a valve wrench could grasp

[image]

UPDATE:

I've removed the shower valve sheath thing. What am I looking at here?

Should I remove this plastic piece or leave it on and find something that fits it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried griping the chrome part of the pipe and turning it counter clockwise ?

Comment: OK - thanks - I was able to remove the chrome sheath. Any tips on what to do now? I've updated my post with the latest.

Comment: You do have the water supply turned off, right ?  Just try to wiggle the plastic cartridge back and forth as you pull straight out on it.